# Zend framework db update not working

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

Am developing an app using zend framework. I want to update some columns in a table using zend db update but its not working. My code is something like this.

```
$where=$table->getAdepter()->quoteInto('from=?',$user_id);
$numrows=$table->update(array('read'=>1),$where);
```

But as I told this is not working. I tried passing where clause as array like this:

```
$table->update(array('read'=>1),array('from'=>$user_id));
```

I also tried passing where as string:

```
$table->update(array('read'=>1),'"from"='.$user_id);
```

But none of these are working. Can anyone help.

Comment: Is this the actual code?

Comment: You've misspelled Adapter in the first line of code.  But since you've tried several methods I would say that's not the issue.

Comment: It would help if you posted more of the code.  For instance what does `$table` represent?  An example that we can run to verify your code would help diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. The problem was about keywords. to and from keywords are reserved in SQL and that was creating problem. I changed the column names and it worked. Thanks all.